# Python Session variable

Tags: python, session-variables, google-app-engine-python

```
def get_items_from_cart(self):
    """ Fetches items from sessions cart"""
    item_list = []
    cart_count = self.session.get('add_to_cart_count')
    if not cart_count: return None;
    for i in range(1, cart_count+1):
        item = self.session.get(str(i))
        if item:
            item_list.append(item)
    return item_list

class AddToCartHandler(Handler):
def get(self):
    if users.get_current_user():
        self.response.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
        get_current_add_count = int(self.session.get('add_to_cart_count'))
        tshirt_id = self.request.get("tshirt_id")
        item_title = self.request.get("item_title")
        qty = self.request.get("qty")
        size = self.request.get("size")
        price = 325
        get_current_add_count += 1
        self.session[get_current_add_count] = { "qty" : qty, "size" : size ,
                                                "item_title": item_title, 
                                                "tshirt_id" : tshirt_id,
                                                "cost" : price * int(qty)}

        current_cart_items = int(self.session.get("item_count"))
        updated_cart_items = current_cart_items + int(qty)
        self.session["item_count"] = updated_cart_items
        self.session["add_to_cart_count"] = get_current_add_count
        self.write(json.dumps({"status" : 1, "msg" : "Order added. <a href='/cart'><span class='label label-success'>View Cart</span></a>"}))
    else:
        self.write(json.dumps({"status" : 0, "msg" : "Please <a href='/login'><span class='label label-important'>login</span> </a>to start shopping!"}))
```

In method "get_items_from_cart" the code depicts fetching values named as numbers and appending the list. those are json encoded (i don't know about json yet).
i want to ask that Does python allows to name a variable in session as number?
Kindly guide me if I'm getting the code in wrong context.

Comment: What prevents you from just trying it?

Comment: want to ask if it's possible to declare numbered variable?

Comment: Try it, just try it!

Comment: What is the sentence *Does python allows to name a variable in session as number?* supposed to mean? You can name a variable `one` if you like, but you cannot name a variable a number, like `17`. Otherwise, I am with Klaus: Try to achieve what you want and when you face a problem, ask a question.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. for motivating me, i was escaping to code managing sessions, but I had to do it.. 
and i MADE it.

Comment: @flaschbier it works, see the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of my question...
this code works fine.

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions
from google.appengine.api import users

class Handle(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        try:
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        return self.session_store.get_session()

class ValTest(Handle):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        val = self.session.get("1")
        val += 1
        self.session["1"] = val
        self.response.write('value is: %i' % val)
        self.response.write('<form method="get" action="/valTst"><input type="submit" name="btn2" value="Incr"></form>')

class MainHandler(Handle):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')
        user = users.get_current_user()
        self.session["1"] = 10
        self.response.write('<form method="get" action="/valTst"><input type="submit" name="btn" value="show"></form>')

### Configuration ###
config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {
    'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',
}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/valTst', ValTest)
], debug=True, config=config)
```